# Prototype inheritance

Tags: javascript, oop

I have done a simple prototype inheritance in java script, here I am passing two parameters title and pays (true or false) if i pass true i am getting "Angular Yes" result but if pass a pays value false i am getting "NaN no" result instead of "HTMl no" i want to print HTMl no

```
//Base Class creation
        var job = function () {
            this.pays = true
        }
        job.prototype.print = function () {

            console.log(this.pays ? 'yse' : 'no')
        }
        //Sub Class creation
        var techjob = function (title, pays) {
            job.call(this);
            this.title = title;
            this.pays = pays;
        }

        techjob.prototype = Object.create(job.prototype);
        techjob.prototype.constructor = techjob;

        job.prototype.print = function () {
            console.log(this.pays ? this.title + " " + 'yes' : + this.title + " " + 'no')
        }

        var subject1 = new techjob("Angular", true);
        var subject2 = new techjob("HTMl", false);

        console.log(subject1.print())
        console.log(subject2.print())

        Result

        Angular yes
        NaN no
```

Comment: Aside from the typo that Schlaus pointed out (the extra `+` before `this.title`), you're assigning two different functions to `job.prototype.print`. I suspect the second one is meant to be assigned to `techjob.prototype.print` instead.

Comment: Note: The *overwhelming* convention in JavaScript is for constructor functions like your `job` and `techjob` to be initially-capped: `Job` and `TechJob`. Obviously you can do anything you like in your code, but when asking for help, it's useful to follow standard conventions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a stray plus-sign in your `print` method. Try this:

```
job.prototype.print = function () {
    console.log(this.pays ? this.title + " " + 'yes' : this.title + " " + 'no')
}
```